# Jinja2-Flask variable partition

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am trying to do partition as it possible in python via jinja2 in my html page. In the code below item.istekteslim_tarihi has value of a date and time such as 2016-04-06 00:00:00

I would like to eliminate time by partition {{item.istekteslim_tarihi}}[:-6] ,seems it is not working. What is the proper way to split the value? I appreciate your help.

```
{% for item in istek %}
           {% for item2 in istekSahibi %}
           {% if item.isteksahibi_id== item2.id%}

                    <li class="list-group-item">{{item.istekteslim_tarihi}}-{{item.id}}-{{item.adi}}-<span style="color:green">{{item.isteksahibi_id}}-{{item2.adi }}-{{item2.soyadi }}</span>- -{{item.verikoordinat_id}}- {{item.istekaciklama}}<a href="/edit_istek/{{item.id}}"><button  type="button">Düzenle/Sil</button></a></li>

           {% endif %}
           {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is a datetime object, you can format it:

```
{{ item.istekteslim_tarihi.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was exactly what I wanted.